# How to do binding in Knockoutjs for asp.net controls

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js, binding, webforms, web-controls

How to do binding in Knockoutjs for asp.net controls? 
I have tried below code but not working.

```
<td data-bind="text: stringValue"></td>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" data-bind="text: stringValue"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Could you show us the HTML output from the above code? It should include the data-bind attribute.

Comment: <td><input data-bind="value: stringValue" /></td>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        stringValue: ko.observable("Hello")
       
    };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>

Comment: That should work fine, http://jsfiddle.net/yogtcgaw/ do you have some javascript on the page failing?

Comment: Will this work for <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" data-bind="text: stringValue"></asp:TextBox> also???

Comment: If it returns the HTML you wrote, it should work, unless some other javascript error occures and stops the binding happening.

Comment: Yes. It's working in jsfiddle. But not in my app.

Comment: Yes, I get that. Knockout works client-side, so if you have the same HTML as in the fiddle (and javascript), it should work. If it doesn't, it must be something else in your client-side code that's not working. So, you don't get ANY javascript errors in your browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind with `value` instead of `text`.

`<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" data-bind="value: stringValue"></asp:TextBox>`